# File browser with Django and Alfresco

Tags: django, alfresco

I have a Django site and a local install of Alfresco (community edition). One of my model contains a file reference which maps to a document in Alfresco. The view should have a field that spawns a file browser that can access the repository structure within Alfresco so that the user can pick whichever file they want at whichever version.

I looked at the [CMSIlib](http://chemistry.apache.org/python/docs/index.html) module and it seems to be providing all the interaction I need for the back end code. Although downloading a document seems [clunky](http://chemistry.apache.org/python/docs/code.html#cmislib.model.Document.getContentStream).

There are lots of [Django file browsers](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/file-managers/) but none seem to interface with [CMSIlib](http://chemistry.apache.org/python/docs/index.html).

*Do I have to code my own or have I missed something?*

The version is `Alfresco Community v5.0.0 (d r99759-b2) schema 8022 Spring Surf and Spring WebScripts - v5.0.0`.

Comment: What version of Alfresco are you using? (API availability and suitability varies with versions)

Comment: @Gagravarr: Information added to the quest. Alfresco Community v5.0.0 (d r99759-b2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I am not a python guy ! But I heard over the official `#alfresco` IRC channel that cmislib is not so much of an active project, and questions about it only bump once in a while .... The RESTful api however may be considered as a good alternative in your use case:

To access alfresco content using the RESTful api, you should be querying this webscript: `/alfresco/d/<d|a>/<workspace>/<store>/<nodeId>/<filename>` 
where :

- `d` and `a` refer to direct / attached mode
- `<workspace>`, `<store>` and `<nodeId>` reference your content nodeRef
- `<filename>` a file name of your choice

So you should be making a `GET` Request an a URL that looks something like this `http://<host>:<port>/alfresco/d/d/workspace/SpacesStore/8444ad61-4734-40e3-b2d4-b8b1c81347fd/myFile.ext`

**Note :** Depending on the permission set on your node, you might need to attach an alf_ticket to the URL for an authenticated alfresco user. Please check [this](http://docs.alfresco.com/community5.0/tasks/ws-specify-user-identity.html) for further insights.

---

**UPDATE 1:**
If you have a problem identifying your file nodeRef, then you can setup a [repo webscript](http://docs.alfresco.com/community5.0/concepts/ws-overview.html) implementing your custom logic (browsing some folder / searching for a document by name or metadata ....)
If your are not familiar with webscript development check [Jeff Pott's tutorial on the subject](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/webscripts/tutorial/tutorial.html)

**UPDATE 2:** 
To get started with your webscript development check out Alfresco docs/wiki!

Check [this wiki page](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Repository_RESTful_API_Reference#Retrieve_list_of_children_.28getChildren.29) to learn how to retrieve children for a given node !
Or check [this wiki page](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Scripts_Examples#Folder_Browse.2FRSS_Feed) to learn how to develop webscripts implementing your custom business logic.

Comment: That would be great for downloading the document but how to I create that reference in the first place?  I want the user to be able to easily select the file without knowing its nodeId, workspace, and store information.  I could live with just the user entering the name of the document (assuming they are unique!) and either a specific version or "latest". But validating that data might be hard.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have anything against the YUI javascript library (that is no longer actively maintained), you can integrate the object-finder already available in Alfresco Share. The library is in

```
share/components/object-finder/object-finder.js
```

You will need to modify it a bit given that you are not inside Share.

To be totally honest, I do not know if it is feasible because it has other dependencies but being a browser site library, in theory can be integrated everywhere.